# ld: library not found for -lclangRewrite

Tags: c++, ios, cmake

The following error occurs when I am building [eos](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos) using cmake on macOS.

```
ld: library not found for -lclangRewrite
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [programs/abi_gen/abi_gen] Error 1
make[1]: *** [programs/abi_gen/CMakeFiles/abi_gen.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 74%] Built target eos_chain
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I find some related issues, but they are seemingly all about ios and xcode and I don't know what I should do in a project like eos. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same 2 errors when building from source code of EOS step by step.
Alternatively You can use another method by running the script(https://github.com/EOSIO/eos#automac):

```
./build.sh darwin
```